# StringConvention.RAW not working with List properties from Spring Cloud

Tags: micronaut, spring-cloud-config

The issue is that i have the following configuration in spring-cloud :

```yaml
config:
  test-lib:
    CODE_1:
      name: name1
      lib:
        - libTitle: title
          libDesc: description
        - libTitle: title
          libDesc: description
    CODE_2:
      name: name2
      lib:
        - libTitle: title
          libDesc: description
        - libTitle: title
          libDesc: description
```

The configuration class looks like:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties("config")
public class Config {


    @MapFormat(keyFormat = StringConvention.RAW)
    private Map<String, Lib> testLib;

}
```

**Behaviour:** 
Below image shows the state of the configuration in debug mode with the config "name" present but "lib" is null 
[Debug mode values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpGFb.png)

**Expected:**
I tried without StringConvention.RAW and it is ok (Below image). 
But i want to keep Map key as it is. In real cases, some codes in the config begin with number (Ex: 1CODE_A_S without RAW gives "1-code-a-s") 
[Debug mode values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRIFT.png)

PS: I also tried to put the configuration inside my micronaut application.yml file with the StringConvention.RAW and it worked fine.